# Detect Image object from UIImage using OpenCV

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am completely new for OpenCV, but during googling I came to know about Object Detection & Edge Detection. But, Still not able to figure out proper way to Detect Image from ScreenShot.

For Example, If I pass an image having photo inside it like below, then I need to extract that Photo from source Image.

[image]

**EDIT**
After following Answer of @Amitay Nachmani, I tried to implement the following code up to step 4.

```
-(UIImage*)processImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage{

    cv::Mat processMat;
    UIImageToMat(sourceImage, processMat);

    cv::Mat grayImage;
    cvtColor(processMat, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat cannyImage;
    cv::Canny(grayImage, cannyImage, 0, 50);


    cv::Vec2f lines2;
    std::vector<cv::Vec2f> lines;
    cv::HoughLines(cannyImage, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 300);

    size_t sizeOfLine = lines.size();
    for(size_t i=0;i<sizeOfLine;i++){
        float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];

        if(rho==0){
            cv::Point pt1,pt2;
            double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
            double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
            pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
            pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
            pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
            pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));

            cv::line(cannyImage, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(255,0,0),2.0);
        }
    }

    UIImage *result = MatToUIImage(cannyImage);
    return result;
}
```

From above code, I got generated following Image.
[image]

**EDIT 2**
I revised code by replacing Condition 
`if(rho==0)` with `if(theta==0)`

This resulted in below Image
[image]

**But, Still What to do next ? I am bit confused in next Steps.**

Comment: Hey Mrug have you find the exact solution..?

Comment: I have same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure but, did you try template matching technique?
If you are using c++ to code opencv: 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

I hope this will be helpful to find cross-correlation between template (your source image) and your test image (screenshot).

In the link below you will find a complete example of how to apply and draw template matching.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Unai.

Comment: Screenshot itself is source image. It's not necessary to match with some predefined image. Just have to extract any image that is placed in white Background or something like that.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but your screenshot has not white background at all, you have text and links, which they are a part of your white background. Anyway I hope that you will be able to discriminate the image taking into account high contrast region of your picture and white background, defining a static intensity threshold .

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the image is always between the second horizontal line and the third i would do the following:

1. Convert to gray scale (opencv cvtColor)
2. Run Canny edge detection (opecv Canny())
3. Find lines using Hough lines (opencv HoughLines() http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)
4. Take only the 4 most prominent horizontal lines ( to take the horizontal ones you need theta = 90)
5. Sort the lines you find according to the y coordinate
6. Crop the image between the second and third line

Comment: Thanks @Amitay, but I am too new to all these things, i will be grateful if you can provide some documents on above things or some code snippets or something like that.

Comment: I edited my Question, with Result Image of Step 4. But stuck after that can u provide more details plsss. Thanks

Comment: I wrote something wrong replace rho = 0 by theta = 90

Comment: None of value has Theta=90, I added output image after Theta=0. It showed only verticle lines.

Comment: I think it is in radians so try pi/2. Also lower the Hugh threshold to 150

Comment: theta =0 gave you the vertical lines

Comment: in opencv you have a constant for pi as CV_PI. so try CV_PI/2

Comment: I tried that too `if(theta==CV_PI/2)` . but it shows nothing :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122823/discussion-between-mrug-and-amitay-nachmani).

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with the post below, this is the best solution but unfortunately, I guess that @Mrug development will be targeted to smartphone devices, and canny edge detection and hough line transform are computationally very expensive from those platforms.

May be you can use Sobel derivates which are designed to calculate horizontal and vertical derivates.

These links may help you:

Sobel Derivates
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html

Canny edge detectors
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html

Hough transform:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html